# Need to create nfc emulator in flutter application

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to create nfc emulator in flutter app using the dart package (https://pub.dev/packages/nfc_emulator)

I have added emulator services to AndroidManifest.xml file and then started getting build error.

This is the emulator service tag of AndroidManifest.xml.

```
<service
    android:name="io.flutter.plugins.nfc_emulator.NfcEmulatorService"
    android:exported="true"
    android:permission="android.permission.BIND_NFC_SERVICE">

    <!-- Intent filter indicating that we support card emulation. -->
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.nfc.cardemulation.action.HOST_APDU_SERVICE" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
    <!--
            Required XML configuration file, listing the AIDs that we are emulating cards
            for. This defines what protocols our card emulation service supports.
    -->
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.nfc.cardemulation.host_apdu_service"
        android:resource="@xml/aid_list" />
</service>
```

This is my dart code:

```
class NFC extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<NFC> createState() => _NFCState();
}

class _NFCState extends State<NFC> {
  // BottomSheetWidget({super.key});
  TextEditingController controller = TextEditingController();

  TextEditingController ctrl = TextEditingController();
  String _platformVersion = 'Unknown';
  NfcStatus _nfcStatus = NfcStatus.unknown;
  bool _started = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    initPlatformState();
  }

  Future<void> initPlatformState() async {
    String? platformVersion;
    NfcStatus nfcStatus = NfcStatus.unknown;
    try {
      platformVersion = await NfcEmulator.platformVersion;
      nfcStatus = await NfcEmulator.nfcStatus;
    } on PlatformException {
      platformVersion = 'Failed to get platform version.';
    }
    if (!mounted) return;
    setState(() {
      _platformVersion = platformVersion ?? 'Unknown';
      _nfcStatus = nfcStatus;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      height: 800,
      color: Colors.white,
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
          // mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: <Widget>[
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 8),
              child: Text('Add details'),
            ),
            TextField(controller: controller, hint: 'cardAid'),
            TextField(
              controller: ctrl,
              hint: 'cardUid',
            ),
            TextButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  startStopEmulator();
                },
                child: Text('Submit'))
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void startStopEmulator() async {
    if (_started) {
      await NfcEmulator.stopNfcEmulator();
    } else {
    await NfcEmulator.startNfcEmulator(
      controller.text,
      ctrl.text,
    );
    //}
  }
}
```

This is the build error that I'm getting.

```
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

I started getting error on adding the emulator services.

Answer (score 0):

minSdkVersion must be 19.

can you change android>app>build.gradle min sdk to upper then 19.

example:

minSdkVersion 21
targetSdkVersion 31
compileSdkVersion 33